# How can I turn off a Mac's display without sleeping the Mac itself?

Tags: imac, music, display, sleep-wake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to put the display to sleep without putting the whole computer to sleep?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/is-it-possible-to-put-the-display-to-sleep-without-putting-the-whole-computer-to)

I have an iMac, and sometimes I want to play some music over night, without the bright display. The display will be turned off automatically several minutes later, but I would like a button that turns the display off instantly and keeps the music playing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> will turn off the displays but leave the computer active.

<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Power ⌽</kbd> for some Macbook

Comment: Not sure why, but it does not work for me - instead of just switching off the screen - it puts computer to sleep. So after I move the mouse and the screen is back on - I need to enter my password again. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Is there a command line way?

Comment: whats the Eject key ? I am using external keyboard

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Del worked for me with "not so magic" keyboard ;)

Comment: This is a horrible answer. What is "eject" and for some users it is sleeping the computer. Same with "hot corner".

Comment: @YemSalat , I don't have the answer but it may be in `pmset`.  Similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311072/macos-high-sierra-restarting-by-itself-during-sleep

Comment: Yep, `pmset displaysleepnow` command did the trick for me. I didn't have mac keyboard and prefer commands as it is. Source [answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/put-the-display-to-sleep-without-putting-the-whole-computer-to-sleep/266103#266103).

Comment: I'm on a 2017 MBP. I don't have an Eject OR a power button 

Answer (score 12):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd> to turn off display.

You can also set a "hot-corner" to turn off display in a few seconds.

Comment: "You can also set a "hot-corner" to turn off display in a few seconds." How?

Comment: Setting a "hot-corner" works through: Apple-Icon -> "System Preferences" -> "Desktop & Screen Saver" -> "Hot Corners...". 
Note: You can also only activate a "Hot Corner" when pressing a key(ctrl, alt, cmd), by pressing that key when assigning the action from this menu.