# Where to find logs for hardware-related shutdowns in OS X 10.11?

Tags: macos, mac-mini, hardware

I have a 2009 Mac Mini running OS X 10.11.6 set up as home theater. Its fan has been quite noisy for a while, but it has still worked fine... until a couple of days ago, when I found out that it had shut down on its own. I turned the Mac again, the fan started making noise... and a few hours later it also shut down on its own (I don't know what message or pop-up it showed, because I have it plugged into my TV, and I didn't have it turned on).

My theory is that the fan couldn't cool the system well enough, so the CPU temp rose so much that OS X shut the computer down on its own, but when I turned it on today and looked on `/var/log/system.log`, I couldn't find any message related to that, nor in any of the other log files available at the Console app.

Where would OS X store logs of such a thing happening, if any?

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311076/85275

Comment: "log: command not found". Do I have to install the Developer Tools?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Maybe the command didn't exist back then. I do have the command line tools installed, but idk whether it belongs to them or to the OS, sorry.