# How to keep MacBook Pro from stopping Time Machine when sleeping?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I don't want to leave my monitor on all the time on my MacBook but would like Time Machine to run when the MacBook screen is off.  My first backup is 500 GB and the computer keeps going to sleep and Time Machine pauses.

Any way to keep Time Machine working but have screen go off only?

Answer (score 1):

If your MacBook supports Power Nap and is connected to power, go to System Preferences → Energy Saver → Power Adapter → Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter. This will allow Time Machine to wake the computer for a backup.

Comment: That is how I have it set, yet it seems to stop Time Machine when sleeping.

Comment: Actually, now that I look back, it's dropbox that stops, time machine keeps going as expected.  Anyway to keep an app awake when computer screen dims?

Comment: @Peter [Put the display to sleep without putting the whole computer to sleep?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27279/37797). Basically: set Energy Saver to not sleep automatically, then use ⌃⇧⏏.