# MacOS - Dim or Sleep external Display without cutting power to peripherals

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, screensaver

I am using a MacBook (M1 MBP Sonoma 14.1.2) with an external display (BenQ P3). The screen acts as a hub and powers my audio interface and external hard drives.

Currently my Mac will go to a screensaver after a while. This is because sleep mode will make my monitor cut the power to the interface and hard drives.

However, having the screen on when I'm simply listening to music feels like a waste of electricity; so here is the question:

**How can I make the screen sleep or at least dim, without cutting power to my peripherals?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the shortcut to 'sleep displays' (found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/put-the-display-to-sleep-without-putting-the-whole-computer-to-sleep)) achieves what I wanted. It is this one: ⌃ + ⇧ + ⏏

This will sleep the external display while it continues powering its hub. As mentioned in the linked answer above you need to use the Power-Button instead of Eject on a modern Mac.